# "git checkout -- *" returns "error: pathspec did not match any files known to git"

Tags: git

As in question, if I want to discard changes in working directory I run command `git checkout -- *` but git returns information `error: pathspec 'databaseName.tmp' did not match any file(s) known to git.`. I'm not git master and I don't know how to solve it. Any idea?

Comment: do you have any untracked files in your working directory?

Comment: That's your problem, you can't check out an untracked file from the index. So instead of just a `*` you need to list only the files you actually want to check out.

Comment: So why git returns information about file that is not on my current branch? Regarding to my current branch status I have some untracked files but as I remember git returns this information always if I want to checkout HEAD files, it doesn't matter that I have untracked files.

Comment: the command `git checkout -- *` is trying to fetch every file in the current directory from the index. Untracked files might as well not exist as far as git is concerned. So when you try to fetch one of them from the index it yells at you.

Comment: You can use `git checkout -- .` instead.

Comment: @genisage, you're right. I found that in some dir I have file `databaseName.tmp`, after I removed it command works properly.

Comment: @pepuch it's taking notice of that file because you told it to, by passing its name on the commandline.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [genisage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681109/genisage) [noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082942/git-checkout-returns-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-known-to-gi#comment44543943_28082942), you're asking git explicitly to check out the file `databaseName.tmp`, as if you'd typed in:

```
git checkout -- databaseName.tmp
```

This is because the `*` you typed in is handled by the shell, before git ever has a chance to see your command.  The shell replaces `*` with all the file names in your current working directory,<sup>1</sup> and then having done that, *then* runs `git`, without any indication that the actual command you entered had `*` in it, rather than all those names.

Again, *git has no idea that you used the asterisk `*` character*, all it sees is a list of file names, *including* any top-level ignored files that are *not being stored in git*.

Confusingly, if you manage somehow<sup>2</sup> to pass a literal asterisk `*` to git, *git* will expand the `*`, but *with a different set of file names:* those known to git.  That would do what you want.

There's an easier way, though: git will check out directories recursively by checking out all the files it knows about *in* that directory.  So, instead of using `*`, simply use `.` to ask git to check out the current directory:

```
git checkout -- .
```

If git knows about `./a` and `./b` but not `./databaseName.tmp`, this will check out `./a` and `./b` and not attempt to do anything with `./databaseName.tmp`.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>More accurately, files whose names do not start with a leading dot `.`.

<sup>2</sup>And in fact, it's quite easy to manage, e.g., simply insert a backslash `\` in front of the asterisk: `git checkout -- \*`.  Or, use single or double quotes, both of which protect against shell globbing.  Single quotes also inhibit shell variable expansion, while double quotes permit variable expansion but inhibit globbing.

<sup>3</sup>It's worth pointing out a subtle difference here: `*` expands to file names that do not start with `.`, while asking git to check out `.` causes it to check out all files in the directory, *including* those whose names start with `.`.  Hence both `git checkout -- \*` and `git checkout -- *` will *not* undo changes to a file named `.secret`, for instance, while `git checkout -- .` *will* undo such changes.

Comment: Just wanted to note that it works with paths too.  If you're in the root of your repo you can do `git checkout -- path/to/files/.` to revert all files in that directory.