# Git checkout: Asterisk pathspec not working

Tags: windows, git, git-checkout

This works fine:

```
git checkout **/pom.xml
```

But we can't run this against another branch

```
git checkout anotherbranch **/pom.xml
git checkout anotherbranch -- **/pom.xml

error: pathspec '**/pom.xml' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

We're on Windows 7/DOS.

Anyone know why?

Note that it works fine without the `**`.   This would checkout the pom.xml from the root.  But we're trying to checkout all pom.xml's that are in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is:

Per [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28083193/47281):

> The shell replaces * with all the file names in your current working
>   directory,1 and then having done that, then runs git

I think that the current branch/working directory has files matching the pathspec that are *not* in `anotherbranch`.  And this is causing the error when we attempt effectively run `git checkout anotherbranch unknown_file`.

Comment: Ah scratch this it's not the issue/answer.  If I clean out those files I still have this issue.  Even if I create a branch off anotherbranch so I have two identical branches I still can't run this command from new branch to checkout these (identical) files on anotherbranch with this pathspec.